# How to do prediction in a binary classification with logistic regression when we care much more about type I error than type II error?

Tags: logistic-regression

How to do prediction in a binary classification with logistic regression when we care much more about type I error than type II error? 
Which criteria should I use to select the threshold value and how should I show different altitude to type I error and type II error?

Comment: If you could quantify the penalty you would pay for a type I error and the penalty you would pay for a type II error, can you select the threshold to minimize the expected penalty?